# Ubuntu 18.04 route to the gateway

Tags: 18.04, netplan

i just start to use the Ubuntu 18.04. When i try to set up the static IPs on that VM. i can't access the internet. But if i switch to use the gateway as the DHCP device, it works. Any idea what went wrong?

Attached is a screenshot for the ouput of route -n and netplan configuration file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1wJy.png)

Here is the output if i switch to use the gateway for DHCP:

```
   root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens6:
#      addresses: [46.16.78.229/24]
      dhcp4: yes
#      nameservers:
#        addresses: [46.16.78.1]
#      routes:
#      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
#        via: 46.16.78.1
#        on-link: true
#      gateway4: 46.16.78.1
    ens7:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.14.160.15/24]

root@ubuntu:~# ip route
default via 46.16.78.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp src 46.16.78.29 metric 100 
10.14.160.0/24 dev ens7 proto kernel scope link src 10.14.160.15 
46.16.78.1 dev ens6 proto dhcp scope link src 46.16.78.29 metric 100 
root@ubuntu:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         46.16.78.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens6
10.14.160.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens7
46.16.78.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens6
```

Comment: Do not post text as images. Copy the relevant text, and apply [code formatting on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
adresses: [46.16.78.229/32]
```

to

```
adresses: [46.16.78.229/24]
```

/32 indicates that it is a subnet with *only* 46.16.78.229 in the network, with no access to any other IP addresses. Thus your computer has no idea of how to reach your configured GW.

Comment: i tried to change to /24, but it still does't work..

Comment: Update your question with the output of `ip route` with the correct configuration.

Comment: just updated the output

Comment: The 'ip route' information shown corresponds to a dhcp-provided route, not to a statically configured route.  This is clearly inconsistent.  Listing /32 in the addresses is clearly wrong, switching this to /24 reliably fixes this problem.

Comment: Indeed. Please provide output of `ip route` when you have the *corrected* configuration in place, not DHCP.